# changing class to an editable table cell

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a question that I'm sure has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find it here.

I have a table cell which contains data loaded from a mysqli db - I limited the size of the cell using css

```
    .hideContent {
        overflow: auto;
        line-height: 1em;
        height: 4em;
    }

    .showContent {
        overflow: auto;
        line-height: 1em;
        height: 40em;
    }
```

In order for the to work, I need to wrap the `<div>` within the `<td>` like so:

```
<td> <div class="hidecontent"> </div> </td>
```

The problem is, this cell is also editable, so when I edit the td, the data saved in the mysqli db contains the `<div>` tag. I do it using someone else's code I found online, sorry for not crediting, I can't remember where I got it.

```
            <div class="hideContent">
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'summary','<?php echo $result['id']; ?>','<?php echo $_GET['customer'] ?>','corr')">
                    <?php echo $result['summary']?>
                </td>
            </div>

function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id,cust_name,db) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveedit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id+'&cust_name='+cust_name+'&db='+db,
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        }        
    });
}
```

And while I'm here, I also want to change the class to "showContent" onClick. Hopefully you can help me :)

To summarize: I want an editable table cell (data to and from mysqli db) that can also dynamically change css styles. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not guide you with full source code.

But, still I can guide you through steps:

1) You have at `<td>` for each data.

2) Add 2 separate elements: a span/div element to show the data.

3) Another text field hidden by default.

4) Firstly, load the span/div with data.

5) Say it has `id="name"`

6) On click it, show the textbox.

7) Get the current id, append '-text' to it.

8) This will be `id` of editable element.

9) Now, you can have editable `<td>`.

10) On blur of textbox, fire AJAX request to save value to database.

11) Also, hide the textbox and show the corresponding span/div (of course with updated value.)

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I quite understand, but I'll give it a go. Appreciate your help.